# How to check facebook graph API for new posts every few seconds?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, scripting, job-scheduling

Facebook has a graph API which you can use to access public facebook posts.  I Want to write a script (PHP?) that will check every few seconds to see if there are new posts for a particularly query and enter the new results into a database.

After the script kicks off I would want it to not stop for a few months and run constantly. Would I have to use some sort of scheduler to  do this or can it be done programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on linux or [scheduled tasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) on Windows to run your php script:

```
 php -f /path/to/script.php
```

Comment: With windows, the task schedule must be 1 minute or greater.  For my task I would like for it to run every few seconds because I need a stream of data to feed to the client browser after it has been inserted into the database.  Can crontab tasks be scheduled in second intervals?

Comment: Wouldn't you hit the request limit pretty soon then?

Comment: @TheTurkish: Yes, crontab is in seconds, however you can not swear on that. It will execute but not exactly at the very second:00.